# How to use curl in python and redirect content into file?

Tags: python, curl

In python I am trying to use `curl` to download an image. I am trying the following command:

```
subprocess.call(['curl',adress,'>',savename])
```

in order to download the content and redirect it into a filename. With this I try to mimic the command line command

```
curl http://my_adress/whatever > test.jpg
```

However, I get gibberish output (the content of the image) and an error saying

```
Could not resolve host: >
```

How to make it right?

Comment: Maybe worse reading: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

Comment: Supplying a command to `subprocess` as individual arguments (rather than as a string) is the right way to do it, but that's because it _prevents_ (accidental or malicious) use of shell features like redirection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
subprocess.check_call(['curl', address], stdout=open(savename, 'w'))
```

then whatever points to `savename` will have your image.

Comment: To be super careful, it should be `with open(savename, 'wb') as f: ...`, but the `b` can't very well make a difference in the child process.